# Global variable loses value after userform

Tags: excel, vba

I know there're several similar questions out there, though I'm afraid none of their answers solve my problem.

I created a simple file to test the problem. Code in Sheet1:

```
Public aaa As String

Sub abc()
    UserForm1.Show
    Debug.Print aaa
End Sub
```

Code in UserForm1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    aaa = TextBox1.Text
    Debug.Print aaa
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

I run the code line by line, the Debug.Print before Unload works fine; and the public var loses its value right after the userform is unloaded.
I've tried to change Unload to Hide, didn't work. The value of the global var loses anyway.

I thought this test file is simple enough to avoid any problem...can anyone tell me why the global var cannot keep its value? Thank you.

Comment: Add new module and move `aaa` variable into it.

Comment: I am afraid that 'the Public variable' was not even used... VBA created a new Variant variable and used it instead. Please, try putting `Option Explicit` on top of the form code module. You must declare the `Public` variable in a Standard module, to be accessed without mentioning the sheet code name... Or try `Sheet1.aaa = TextBox1.Text`. It couldn't loose what it did not have.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now I know what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No variable ever "loses" it's value. Your problem comes from the fact that the `aaa` in your sheet module and the `aaa` in the form are different variables. Why is that?

a) Sheets are similar to classes. If you declare `Public aaa As String` within the sheet module, you can access it *within* that sheet module with it's name. Outside of that module, you need to specify the object, eg `sheet1.aaa`.

b) As a consequence, in the form code the variable `aaa` is not known. As it seems you don't use `Option Explicit`, the VBA runtime will create it on the fly and assign the content of the Textbox to it.

So the variable `aaa` defined in sheet is never touched. You can easily proof this by assigning anything to it in your `abc` routine before you open the form and check `aaa` in your form code - you will not see any content. When returning back to `abc`, the original content is still there.

What can you do?
As already said, you could use `sheet1.aaa` within your code.

An alternative is to move the declaration of `aaa` into a regular module (my advice would be to move also the Sub `abc` into that module - sheet code should contain only event handler). Defined in a regular module, `aaa` would be a global variable that is known also in the form code.

To avoid such problems, you should use `Option Explicit`. With that, the compiler would tell you that `aaa` is undefined in the form module.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had left variable with same name inside module and the other module, that initializes global variables. Hopefully will help some lost soul.